# Is the folder ~/.stack a system folder?

Tags: macos

I'm clearing off space from my 256GB internal hard disk using DaisyDisk.  I've come across a 3GB hidden folder called ".stack" in my home directory.  I can't remember whether I ever had an application called "stack" -- a short Google search only came up with Apple's Stacks.

Is this a MacOS or system folder which I should leave alone, or is it fine to delete it?  If there's any doubt, I'll leave it be, but otherwise 3GB is space I could use.  This is the content of the folder -- it seems to be a few years old.

[image]

(For what it's worth, I'm running 10.14.6).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

~/.stack is created by the Haskell Tool Stack (https://haskellstack.org).

As it is a folder in your home directory, it is safe for the system to remove, but the software will be reset to its initial state. You may wish to [uninstall](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/#how-to-uninstall) the software too.

Answer (score 2):

Anything in your HOME directory is ***not*** a system file; by definition, it’s a **user** file.  It’s located in the `/Users/username` directory.

Is it safe to delete?

- From a system perspective, yes.  Deleting it will not affect your system whatsoever.
- From an application perspective, yes.  Deleting it will not “break” the application that uses it.
- From the perspective of *your* configuration/settings of the application, you run the risk of losing your saved settings, but they can always be recreated.